# CSS transition does not trigger on adding class on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone have any idea why my css transitions  won't work inside an event listener? If I call it directly it works. when I call it inside an event listener it does not work

```
let start_session = ()=>{
  let pomodoro = set_up()  
  let _pomodoro_container = pomodoro_container()
  let _session_ui = session_ui()
  let time_init = gms(pomodoro.clock.work.time)
 // console.log(time_init)
  update(pomodoro,time_init.min,time_init.sec)

  //works
 // trigger_anim()

  _pomodoro_container.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  //does not work
    //trigger_anim()
    if(pomodoro.state.state==pomodoro.states.before_start||pomodoro.state.state==pomodoro.states.paused)
      start(pomodoro)
    else pause(pomodoro)
  },false)

  _session_ui.work.up.addEventListener('click',()=>{ 
    let value = (Number(_session_ui.work.div.dataset.work)+1)
    _session_ui.work.div.dataset.work = value
    _session_ui.work.display.firstChild.textContent =value
    reset_on_update(pomodoro)
  },false)

  _session_ui.work.down.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    let value = (Number(_session_ui.work.div.dataset.work)-1)
    _session_ui.work.div.dataset.work = value
    _session_ui.work.display.firstChild.textContent =value
    reset_on_update(pomodoro)
  },false)

  _session_ui.break.up.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    let value = (Number(_session_ui.break.div.dataset.break)+1)
    _session_ui.break.div.dataset.break = value
    _session_ui.break.display.firstChild.textContent =value
    reset_on_update(pomodoro)
  },false)

  _session_ui.break.down.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    let value = (Number(_session_ui.break.div.dataset.break)-1)
    _session_ui.break.div.dataset.break = value
    _session_ui.break.display.firstChild.textContent =value
    reset_on_update(pomodoro)
  },false)

  return pomodoro
}

let trigger_anim =()=>{
let _pomodoro_container = pomodoro_container()
  insert_style_sheet_with_rule("div._test{transition:background 6s ease}")
  _pomodoro_container.classList.add("_test")
}
```

The class does get added to the div, but the transition does not trigger.

Other css proeprties like say, background or border do change

```
let insert_style_sheet_with_rule = (rule)=>{
  let new_style = document.createElement('style')
  style.replaceWith(new_style)
  style = new_style
  style.sheet.insertRule(rule,style.sheet.cssRules.length)
}
```

I'm inserting a stylesheet because i need to be able to change the length of the transition, and can't simply add/remove a class

Comment: Why can't you simply modify the `transition-duration` using JS then?

Comment: does not work, even transition property specified in the css file do not take effect, but others do

Comment: Not that you can have only one `transition` declaration active at once. The last one wins and overwrites all others. If you need to specify different transitions, separate them by comma.

Comment: I have specified a single transition on background in the stylesheet.I add/remove the class via classList. It's not triggering the transition at all.

Comment: If the class is specified/added in the html, or outside a click listener, it works

Comment: Please make a working snippet from your code on e.g. jsfiddle or codepen.